# Python VS code detect incorrect argument name

Tags: python, visual-studio

How can I make VS code detect incorrect argument names?

```
def test_function(name1, name2, name3):
    print(name1)
    print(name3)
    print(name2)

test_function(name1=1, name2=2, name4=4)
```

Currently, VS code doesn't flag this as an error. Detecting this would be very useful since argument names change. Otherwise you get an error at run time which is far too late.

Answer (score 0):

VS code is a text editor that one can use to write code in multiple languages but is not a Python interpreter. What you can do is install an extension to do that. For example: [`Python` from Microsoft](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), has a linter that shows you what problems your code has, including the kind of problem you're describing. Make sure you read the docs to configure it correctly.